# Inconsistent date returned from UNIX stamp with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to use Moment.js to display a date from a UNIX timestamp, but the results are inconsistent.

The code that I use to convert the stamp is this:

```
var timestamp = Moment.unix(this.props.date/1000).format('ddd Mo MMMM').toString();

console.log(this.props.date, timestamp);
```

Yet what is returned in the browser looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It would be much better to post actual code to save transcription errors and to show entire dates, not just the day and month. 1475100000000  is 2016-09-28T22:00:00.000Z (Wednesday) and 1456786800000 is 2016-02-29T23:00:00.000Z (Monday) and `new Date(1475100000000/1000)` is 1970-01-18T01:45:00.000Z.

Comment: I've changed the image for you to give you more information. The dates are closer when using /1000 rather than times or even the original value. Does this have anything to do with daylight saving?

Answer (score 0):

1) I have never seen moment is used with `Moment` constructor . Couldn't find it in their doc as well . It's generally used as `moment(this.props.date/1000, 'UNIX').format("ddd Mo MMMM")`.

2) Unix timestamp is a number . I see it's getting printed as string in an array in your case . That might be the cause of inconsistency as well.

Comment: I use this method to be able to 'require' the module in React.

Comment: @JohnRobertPett did unpacking your array before passing it to moment solved your problems?

Comment: I changed to this formatting and it fixed for me: var timestamp = Moment.unix(this.props.date/1000).format('ddd Do MMMM').toString();